# mySQL query: find what contains a keyword and the number of objects having the keyword

Tags: mysql

I need to find all the object's that contain a specific keyword, together with the amount found.
I already started with it, but don't know how to find the amount. I properly need to use COUNT but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
select object
from object o
where o.CTN like '%keyword%';
```

Another thing is, to only get the CTN that are shared by more than 3.

Comment: If your database has any significant number of records, this is going to be horrifically slow. MySQL simply isn't capable of doing what you're asking in a performant way. To do this kind of thing on a meaningful amount of data, you're going to need some kind of dedicated search tool such as Elasticsearch.

Comment: It is being used together with a prototype, which gathers the data. So the amount of record is below 50. which I believe MySQL should be able to handle at a reasonable pace. At least that's what I'm told. I'm no expert here.

Comment: Fair enough. 50 records in a prototype system won't kill you. But the point is that doing a `%substring%` search in SQL basically means it has to do a full table scan and string match of every single record each tim you do the query; fine for 50 records; not fine for 50 thousand, and unusable if you have 50 million. If you're adding layers on top of that to do count the number of results per record, then the performance will be even worse.

Comment: A basic fast indexing solution with Elasticsearch would give you near-instantaneous results for this even with vast amounts of data. If your prototype is going to remain a prototype with 50 records forever, then don't worry about it, but if it's ever going to get more data than that, then you do need to be thinking about these things at the prototype stage, or it will bite you later on, and probably sooner than you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT object, FLOOR(((CHAR_LENGTH(object) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(object, 'keyword', ''))) / CHAR_LENGTH('keyword'))) AS cnt_matches
FROM object o
WHERE o.object LIKE '%keyword%'
HAVING cnt_matches > 3
```

You can also create a function to reuse this expression:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION GetStringCount(strValue VARCHAR(200), charValue VARCHAR(200))
RETURNS INTEGER DETERMINISTIC NO SQL
BEGIN
  RETURN (CHAR_LENGTH(strValue) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(strValue, charValue, ''))) / CHAR_LENGTH(charValue);
END
```

So your query looks like this:

```
SELECT object, GetStringCount(object, 'keyword') AS cnt_matches
FROM object o
WHERE o.object LIKE '%keyword%'
HAVING cnt_matches > 3
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b408b6384a58f7d4db19432621f01228)